# How do I redirect PlayOnLinux to a different partition?

Tags: wine, symbolic-link

Okay! This sounds kind of hard, but it should be entirely doable.

I have Ubuntu and Windows on the same disk. On the Windows partition, I have a game installed (Guild Wars 2, but this shouldn't matter). Upon booting up Ubuntu, the Windows partition is mounted under "/home/ruben/Windows". Under Windows, my game folder would be in "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArenaNet\Guild Wars 2". So under Ubuntu, it's in "/home/ruben/Windows/Program Files (x86)/ArenaNet/Guild Wars 2".

Now, because I want to save space, and because I want to be able to access the game from both Ubuntu and Windows, I want to create a path to "/home/ruben/Windows/Program Files (x86)/ArenaNet/Guild Wars 2" for PlayOnLinux. PlayOnLinux, per default, installs Guild Wars 2 in this folder:

"/home/ruben/.PlayOnLinux/wineprefix/GuildWars2/drive_c/Program Files (x86)/ArenaNet/Guild Wars 2"

So what I want to do is create a fake folder in "/home/ruben/.PlayOnLinux/wineprefix/GuildWars2/drive_c/Program Files (x86)" that redirects to "/home/ruben/Windows/Program Files (x86)/ArenaNet". Can this be done?

What I've tried doing is this:

```
sudo ln -s "/home/ruben/Windows/Program Files (x86)/ArenaNet" "/home/ruben/.PlayOnLinux/wineprefix/GuildWars2/drive_c/Program Files (x86)"
```

But it doesn't appear to work, as PlayOnLinux gives me errors about not finding the folder.

Any help would be so much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Speak of the devil. I deleted Guild Wars 2 inside POL and ran the installation procedure of Guild Wars 2 again until it reached about 300 MB for good measure. I then deleted the ArenaNet folder POL had created, and made the symbolic link described in my question.

```
sudo ln -s "/home/ruben/Windows/Program Files (x86)/ArenaNet" "/home/ruben/.PlayOnLinux/wineprefix/GuildWars2/drive_c/Program Files (x86)"
```

And it worked! So soon after posting my question. I hope this helps anyone else, then.